# How can make finding items in array became more efficient when using for loop in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am aware of use case of Higher order functions in Swift and I know how I can use them for solving issues like this, but in my question I am looking to find an approach which does not use those easy ready functions, and I am trying to optimize the finding process when looping in all member of array. Can I do more optimization in term of better performance when working with very big arrays for finding items which we are looking for index of them?

```
func test() {
    
    let array: Array<String> = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "Hello, world!", "B", "C", "Hello", "W"]
    
    for index in array.indices {
        if array[index].contains("Hello") {
            print(index)
        }
    }

}
```

results:

4

7

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to check if a specific string is a substring of any elements of a collection of strings?

Comment: Exactly, I know the use case of Set and Dic, but since order of items is very important, I am working with array.

Comment: Good fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jnpdx: You mean I should ask my question there?

Comment: @ioscoder Yes -- that site is basically focused on reviewing existing code that works, but making it more efficient, safer, etc

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is currently `O(n)` (ignoring for now the variable run time of `contains()`).

When it comes to search algorithms on arrays of data with no constraints, that's as good as it gets. You have to check every element and there's no way around it.

Optimizations can be made when you have more information about the array. For example, if an array is sorted, you can make a search algorithm that is `O(log(n))`, which is much faster. If the order of the array didn't matter, you could sort it before hand, which would be expensive but would only be done once, and every query would be quicker.

Another option for optimizing is, if you know that the same query may run multiple times, you can cache the results and reuse them.

You can also try to get clever and prepare some "metadata" on your array in order to make your lookup faster.

For example, you could create a duplicate array that contains a sorted version of the array where each element contains the string value as well as its original index, then you use a binary search to find matching elements in `O(log(n))`, and now you have the indices a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks for your info and help. I think I got my answer but I got a question from your answer, for me and for my app the order is very important, if i ignore order of items, is there any room to improvement without using higher order functions but of curse using Set or Dic? because I can order the result of search at end as well. And create an array from Set or Dic in case. Or should I make new question about it?